# how do i subclipse plugin in eclispe to revise files then run in tomcat

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, subclipse

I haven't used eclipse in a while and I need someone to help me with a problem I'm having.  There's a project in a Subversion repository and I need to update a few JSPs.  I have installed eclipse, subclipse plugin and running tomcat within the eclipse IDE.  What is the best way to get the project (in subversion) into eclipse, edit the files, save & run them in tomcat (localhost - so that I can see my changes in the browser), all within Eclipse?

I tried:

- within my workspace using eclipse, create a new project and import the project from svn into the newly created project
- directly importing the project by selecting FILE -->"import" -->
  "Create a new project by checking out an existing project from a SVN
  repository"

Neither of these methods will show the project in the "Add and Remove Projects" dialog box for tomcat to run it.  I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Thanks.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

After three days of trying to get this question answered on different forums and googles, I've finally found the answer I was looking for.  You can view it at  [Using Subclipse (the Subversion Plug-in for Eclipse) for Configuration Management](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/subclipse/)  Hope this helps anyone interested.